# Regular expression to match numbers, but not HTML entities

Tags: php, regex

Is there a regex to find all the digit sequences (`\d+`) in text, but not the ones forming HTML entities? Look like I should use both "look ahead" and "look behind" together, but I can’t figure out how.

For example, for the string `&#10001; #555 foo 777;` I want to match only `555` and `777`, but not `10001`.

I’ve tried

```
~(?<!(&#)|\d])\d+(?![\d|;])~
```

But it seems to be too strict, as it returns no matches for cases like `777;`

Comment: did you try anything yet?

Comment: You should at least show us what you have tried ? Also can those numbers have decimal points in them, or ordinary integers ?

Comment: Can you give some example input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve found the solution the next morning.

```
(?<![(&#)\d])\d+|\d+(?!\d|;)
```

It's quite big and poorly readable, but it works. 
P.S. I think it’s a lot easier just do decode/hide the entities before processing and then put them back.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use this regex with lookarounds:

```
(?<!&#)\b\d+\b|(?:^|\b)\d+\b(?!;|$)
```

#### Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/IUGqDf7Nfg

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that does not work for the sequences like `789;` or `&#789`.

Comment: That's why folks were asking you provide sample inputs in question :P I will edit my answer

Comment: Thanks, but it does not catch all the possible digits in text.
http://www.rubular.com/r/itLhjj0NHe - this one’s better